# Java nested while loops

Tags: java, while-loop, nested-loops

I need nested while loops to print so that the outter loop k  makes one decrement iteration every time that inner loop "I" finishes an iteration. K has to start at 5 and count back to 1 and I has to starts at 0 and count to 10 by 2's. So it would the out put would look like this:

```
K = 5 I = 0
K = 5 I = 2
K = 5 I = 4
K = 5 I = 6
K = 5 I = 8
K = 5 I = 10
K = 4 I = 0
```

I have been stumped for hours and tried everyway to I can think of to make it work. Can someone please help?

```
public class Task1 {
public static int i = 0;
public static int k = 5;

public static void Display(){

    while(k > 1){

        while(i >=10){
            i = i+2;
            System.out.println("K = " + k + " I = " + i);

        }


        if (i >= 10){
            k=k-1;
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Display();

}
    }
```

Comment: Why use while loops? This is normally done as `for( int i = 5; i > 0; i-- ) for( int j = 0; j <= 10; j = j+2 ) System.our.println( i + " " + j);` of course making same with whole loops is trivial if you have seen that a `for` loop is very much like a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few errors. Follow the comments

```
while(k >= 1){                                        // Make it >= instead of >

    i = 0;                                            // reset i
    while(i <=10){                                    // Make it i<= (less than)
        System.out.println("K = " + k + " I = " + i); //print before incrementing
        i = i+2;

    }
```

Rest of the code is correct. And the output is as expected

```
K = 5 I = 0
K = 5 I = 2
K = 5 I = 4
K = 5 I = 6
K = 5 I = 8
K = 5 I = 10
K = 4 I = 0
K = 4 I = 2
K = 4 I = 4
K = 4 I = 6
.
.
.
```

Comment: this works but for some reason k is stopping before it goes to 1 and prints the last iteration. any idea why? thanks for all of the help

Comment: @user2796618 Just make it `>=` in the while loop. Check the edit

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. I needed an = in the first while thanks for helping everyone

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `i` before the start of the *inner* loop, inside the outer loop, so it gets reset each time

Comment: Now my out put looks like this :     K = 5 I = 2
K = 5 I = 4
K = 5 I = 6
K = 5 I = 8
K = 5 I = 10
K = 4 I = 12
K = 3 I = 2
K = 3 I = 4
K = 3 I = 6
K = 3 I = 8
K = 3 I = 10
K = 2 I = 12

Comment: Note that every `I` printed is 2 too big; I'll leave fixing that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(k > 1) {
   i = 0;
   while( i <= 10) { 
     Print
      i += 2;
   }
   k--;
 }
```

Your inner while loop condition was incorrect. And you were adding to i too soon so you would never print for 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public class Task1 {
public static int i = 0;
public static int k = 5;

public static void Display(){

    while(k > 0){
        i = 0;
        while(i <= 10){
            System.out.println("K = " + k + " I = " + i);
            i+=2;
        }
        k--;

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display();

}
}
```

Comment: Your inner while loop should be less than or equal to.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your display method with this..

```
public static void Display(){

       while(k > 1){
          i=0; //initialise i back to 0
          while(i <=10){ //Change >= to <=
               i = i+2;
               System.out.println("K = " + k + " I = " + i);
          }
         k--;
        //comment or delete below if block
        /*if (i >= 10){
           k=k-1;
        }*/
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code.

```
public class Task1 {

public static int i = 0;
public static int k = 5;

public static void Display() {

    while (k >= 1) { // use >=1 if you wanna print till 1
        i = 0; // set i=0
        while (i <= 10) {
            System.out.println("K = " + k + " I = " + i); // add print
                                                            // statement
            i = i + 2;

        }
        k--; // no need to use if (i >= 10){ }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Display();

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
for(int k = 5;k>0;k--;){
for(int i = 0;i<10;i+=2;)
 System.out.println(k+ "" +i)
}
```